# the difference between by -ing form and -ing form

Tags: sentence-construction, participle-phrases

This question involves the difference between **-ing** form and **by -ing** form.

The passage below is from a few steps guided on Microsoft's website as to how to renew a one-year subscription of Microsoft Office 365.

> Go to Office.com/setup and, if prompted, sign in **using** the Microsoft account that’s associated with your Office 365 subscription.

I am wondering whether the sentence would be still correct and mean the same thing with ***using*** changed into ***by using*** as follows.

> Go to Office.com/setup and, if prompted, sign in **by using** the Microsoft account that’s associated with your Office 365 subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Open the door using this key.
>
> Open the door by using this key.

The preposition **by** casts its object as an instrumentality, a means-by-which; since the verb **use** already has this meaning, the version with the preposition simply reinforces the meaning of the verb.

.

Comment: Thank you so much for your elegant answer as always. And if I may check this, ***the verb*** you mentioned at the end of the answer means the verb **using**, right?

Comment: @SmartHumanism: Yes, the verb **use** means "to employ something as an instrument".   Its participle is **using**.

Comment: Thank you again for the kind answer. And I've learn the use of **cast** and **employ** from your answers as well. I saw several times you use those verbs when explaining. I think it seems to be neat uses of those verbs. :)